# cakephp 3.x and htaccess mod_rewrite make my sessions disappear

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-3.0

When you google for this problem, one can find lots of simular problems but no single solution.

I've got this website:

```
www.website.com
```

My CakePhp 3.x project is located in this directory

```
www.website.com/project
```

Sessions are used in a previous project so I have to customise the session in app.php in order to access them

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'PHPSESSID',
    'timeout' => '20000',
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_domain' => '.website.com',
        'session.save_path' => '/var/www/clients/client1/web/tmp/',
    ]
],
```

**!! All is fine browsing http://www.website.com/project It keeps the session intact!!**

In htaccess I make the /project folder invisible so:

```
http://www.website.com/project becomes http://www.website.com/
http://www.website.com/project/start becomes http://www.website.com/start
...
```

**Now; http://www.website.com/ and http://www.website.com/start are loosing my  sessions**

This is my htaccess-file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !website.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 

#rewrite previous project to root
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.website\.com\/sys" [R=301,L]

#do nothing with these urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/portret/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/temp/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tempcs/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tempmail/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tempsoc/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tempzip/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/.*$


#disable project folder to make it nice
RewriteRule (.*) /project/$1 [QSA,L]


#fixing some pains-in-the-ass
Redirect 301 /FDM   http://old-website/web/index1.php?ID=FDM
Redirect 301 /GM   http://old-website.be/web/index1.php?ID=GM
Redirect 301 /FC   http://old-website.be/web/index1.php?ID=FC

#set the root
DirectoryIndex project/search/start
```

**Some debug-info:**

> session_get_cookie_params

```
Array ( [lifetime] => 0 [path] => /project/ [domain] => .website.com [secure] => [httponly] => 1 )
```

> CakePhp Debugkit Cookie Request on a page without /project

```
__unameb00ce0-152452f3c4a-10c277e4-12
PHPSESSID j1guvr5armlfpa7aa64aa9lfe1
_gaGA1.2.1776275125.1452677383
_gat1
```

> CakePhp Debugkit Cookie Request on a page with /project

```
search Q2FrZQ==.MWQ3MzRhMWY3YWVmMzY0OGEzN2QwODFjMmY0MDE3NTdiOTI4OTQ5NDYxNmNhNmYwNzMyMjRmOTExNDA5NDJlOR+xldRH1lAaIbKGzowwWjtleNpkY/NYKZjft08u3Q8C
PHPSESSID 3amnr19lag1l0s7v5f20us4rq7
language Q2FrZQ==.ZDdjOWQ2NmI2ZDhiNWYzZGM2Zjg4MjRkM2NjMzRjMGRiMmM3NzM4MmEzMzRmZTFkNDI2NDhkY2U4MjBhOGZjM/ARPIqb98q5NwFN9JLi/HelqGCM6V3bsdCFlxxOkI/z
__unameb00ce0-152452f3c4a-10c277e4-12
_gat1
_gaGA1.2.1776275125.1452677383
```

Comment: Could you add the result of "session_get_cookie_params" in your question?

Comment: I added some more debug info, you can clearly see that it creates a new session ID

Comment: Why is the session_get_cookie_params path /project/? Are you sure that "/var/www/clients/client1/web/tmp/" exists?

Answer (score 0):

The following settings worked for me:

```
'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'ini' => [
            'session.cookie_path' => '/'
        ]
    ],
```